# SSHD keeps asking for user password even though it was configured with publickey,keyboard-interactive

Tags: ssh, configuration

I'm trying to configure sshd on a VPS instance, and would like to have an authentication witch is publickey,keyboard-interactive (public key AND keyboard-interactive).

The problem is that the server keeps asking for serveruser password on login after the public key was sent and accepted. It should only ask for the 2FA code.
I am able to login using publickey, serveruser password and 2FA code.

I have two other similar setups that work great but I remember having trouble setting those up, like using black magic in bizarre configuration files.

I spent countless hours trying to configure sshd this way on other hosts and now I don't seem to achieve it.

I also tried to compare client and server logs on a working setup and this one but the logs are the same! (Except with IPs, ports and fingerprints)

SSH client log : https://pastebin.com/P1xsKTwm

Server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config : https://pastebin.com/qSH7GAmR

Server's /etc/pam.d/sshd : https://pastebin.com/YBKY91Rk

(sshd was restarted using `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`)

**EDIT : keyboard-interactive is not only for 2FA**

Read the comments in mforsetti's answer below, I did not understood that keyboard-interactive was not for 2FA only.

The trick was to edit `/etc/pam.d/sshd` file to disable password authentication *(explained in mforsetti's post and comments below)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that the server keeps asking for serveruser password on login after the public key was sent and accepted.

well, you specifically asked for it.

> ```
> AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
> ```

Quoting [`sshd_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#AuthenticationMethods) manual,

> AuthenticationMethods
>
> Specifies the authentication methods that must be successfully completed for a user to be granted access. ... by the single string `any` to indicate the default behaviour of accepting any single authentication method ...
>
> ... For example, "publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive" would require the user to complete public key authentication, followed by either password or keyboard interactive authentication. ...

So, adding `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive` to your `sshd_config`, means you expect to have `publickey` authentication completed first, then `keyboard-interactive` authentication completed next.

If you expect to only authenticate with `publickey`, probably change

> ```
> AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive
> ```

to

> ```
> AuthenticationMethods publickey
> ```

or, if you enable any other authentication methods and expect any single successful authentication method as an OK, you may use

> ```
> AuthenticationMethods any
> ```

---

> I want to authenticate both with public key and 2FA

You may want to disable `common-auth` from PAM configs, as in most Linux/Unix distributions, `common-auth` includes `pam-unix.so` or `pam-unix2.so` which requires account password.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  :D Maybe I was not clear above, I want to authenticate both with public key and 2FA but not the serveruser password.  

What I don't understand is that keyboard-interactive keeps asking me for serveruser's password ; it shouldn't right, it's only 2FA?

Comment: `keyboard-interactive` is a catch-all key for, well, keyboard interactivity, including password, PAM, Kerberos, etc. try using `AuthenticationMethods publickey,keyboard-interactive:pam` if you're using PAM to configure your 2FA stuff.

Comment: have you commented `@include common-auth` in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`?

Comment: Ohhh... I thought that keyboard-interactive was only for 2FA... Commenting the line did exactly what I wanted to do, many thanks!

Comment: added info about `common-auth` in the answer.

Comment: great! :D many thanks!

Comment: @mforsetti I'm having the same issue I followed this guide to https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/aws-mfa-ssh-ec2-setup/ to Enable 2FA to an AWS EC2 instance with AWS AMI. according to the guide he says the user accounts which did not run the google authentication initialization should not be prompted with MFA key. when trying to access it via termius its prompting anyways for users who have not setup google authentication

Comment: @IsmailIqbal no that's a different issue. try making a new question in detail about what you've configured in the instance.